# XCode- is it possible to add columns and images to PickerView in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, picker

Is it possible to add images and columns to Picker View in XCode Interface Builder?

Image here:

[image: example]
http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_l5fgqaBrEo1qar71d.jpg

I'm supposed to come up with something similar.. and I'm quite new to developing iphone app, but do have experience of C#/Java...

any tips/inputs?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just return a UIView from the picker's delegate's [viewForRow:forComponent:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/viewForRow:forComponent:) method.

Answer (score 0):

What chrispix says is correct. but you can't create the whole view using Interface Builder